# SQL::Abstract - Matching Value Against Column Operation

Tags: sql, perl

Using SQL::Abstract, how would I build up this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1*col2 = 4;
```

Can't for the life of me find any examples on how to make the left side of the operation something custom rather than just a column.

Best I can do is get SQL::Abstract to pass the col1*col2 with quotes around it, but then that breaks the multiplication.

**Edit:** The best solution would be one that would take *any* kind of operation on the left side, not just the multiplication example.  For example, if I wanted to do something slightly more complicated: (col1*col2)-col3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
use v5.16;
use warnings;

use SQL::Abstract;

my $sqlab = SQL::Abstract->new;

my ($stmt, @bind) = $sqlab->select('mytable', '*', { '(col1*col2)-col3' => 4 });

use Data::Dump;
dd $stmt;
dd @bind;
```

**output**

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ( (col1*col2)-col3 = ? )"
4
```

Comment: In my code, the junk in the column identifier wasn't working, but clearly this is the solution.  So I'll have to dig around and see what's going wrong for me.

Answer (score 0):

The doc leads me to think this is how you do it, but I haven't tried:

```
'col1' => { '*' => { -ident => 'col2' } }
```

but I'm not sure how you then compare that to 4.

Comment: Not quite.  This produces "select * from mytable where col1 * col2"

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code that generates queries; I don't remember how and am too lazy to read that part of the doc

Comment: `my $qargs = {
  where    => { col1 => 'somevalue',
                              col2 => 'somevalue',
    },
 };`

Comment: err, I mean the part that takes that and prints out the generated SQL

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's just: 

`my ($sql, @bind) = SQL::Abstract->new('tablename',\@desiredcolumns,\%whereclause,\@sortorder);`  

I build all those args up in my $qargs.

And then you get your sql string in $sql and your values in @bind.